# Unresolved externals problem in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am currently trying to learn C++ using Bjarne Stroustrup's PPP, and I have a little problem. This is probably an incorrect form of the question, but I haven't found any solution on the internet.
So, this is a program that I copied from the official website.
(https://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator02buggy.cpp)

The code itself, I think, doesn't really matter here. The problem is that VS gives me the error
`1 unresolved external object` and `unresolved external symbol "public: class Token __cdecl Token_stream::get(void)" (?get@Token_stream@@QEAA?AVToken@@XZ) referenced in function "double __cdecl expression(void)" (?expression@@YANXZ)`

By the way, I used the console application option to create a project. This is the only thing I could find on this issue.

Comment: This code purposely contains errors. You have `get` implementation in the code but is  without  class prefix. Should be`Token_stream::get()`.